# suffix: -acea, -aceae (any difference of pronunciation and the right pronunciation?)

Tags: suffixes

> -acea, -aceae

What is the right pronunciation?

What is the difference?

Comment: Is this related to botany?

Comment: yes, in case of '-aceae', but zoology in case of '-acea'

Comment: I just spent a couple of minutes searching the full OED, but I can't find even a single word there that ends with ***-aceae***. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-acea) says *In botany, the suffix is **-aceae**, from the fem. plural of **-aceus**, forming orders or families of plants (**Rosaceae**, etc.)* But the OED only has ***rosacea***, which is a completely different word.

Comment: Merriam-Webster: [**rosaceae**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Rosaceae) Ro·​sa·​ce·​ae | \ -āsēˌē \  . . . .  [**rosacea**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rosacea) ro·​sa·​cea | \ rō-ˈzā-sh(ē-)ə

Comment: Incidentally I do not agree with Merriam-Webster so there may be dialect differences here.

Comment: These are not native suffixes, but rather derived from Greek or Latin. Moreover, they are used within technical terms in specialized fields. How they are actually pronounced by specialists in the field is probably best answered by the specialists themselves or by a technical dictionary.

Comment: My dictionary(one of asian ones) says: [éisiì:] for '-aceae' which is used for family names in botany, and [éiʃiə] for '-acea' used for class/order names in zoology.

Comment: Whilst this question has its faults, it shows no research effort and asks about pronunciation which we don't do here "Basic questions on spelling, meaning or pronunciation are off-topic as they should be answered using a dictionary." It's worth pointing out that none of our regular contributors can find satisfactory answers in their dictionary research. Hence I'm voting to leave this open for now in case someone can provide an authoritative answer.